# Quotes in JSON throw jQuery error, even though they're escaped

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using PHP to fetch JSON stored in a MySQL database, put it into a PHP variable,  and pass it to JQuery, which writes the content to the page:

```
data = $.parseJSON('<?=$my_json;?>'); 
$.each(data.links, function(entryIndex, entry) {
    //do some stuff here
        });
```

Everything works fine when the JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "links": [{
        "url": "http://domain1.com",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "This is an example for my question on Stack Overflow"
    }, {
        "url": "http://domain2.com",
        "title": "Title 2",
        "description": "This is another example for my question on Stack Overflow"
    }, {
        "url": "http://domain3.com",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "description": "This is a third example for my question on Stack Overflow"
    }]
}
```

But when the JSON content includes quotes, I get an error reading "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input," even though the quotes are escaped, like this:

```
{
    "links": [{
        "url": "http://domain1.com",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "This is an \"example\" for my question on Stack Overflow"
    }, {
        "url": "http://domain2.com",
        "title": "Title 2",
        "description": "This is another \"example\" for my question on Stack Overflow"
    }, {
        "url": "http://domain3.com",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "description": "This is a third \"example\" for my question on Stack Overflow"
    }]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you have shown should work fine. Are you sure that's what is contained in `$my_json`? Check there's no line breaks in the output too, as JS will throw an error in that instance as well.

Comment: You should be able to code `data = <?=$my_json;?>; `

Comment: Can you post the rendered javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = $.parseJSON('<?=$my_json;?>');
```

The thing you're doing here is you're trying to wrap up the JavaScript object around quotes and passing it as a string to `$.parseJSON` function.

This function only parses JSON string which is a string should be formed with JSON structure and that will then converted to a JavaScript object by the function.

While `$my_json` variable already has a JavaScript object, you don't need to use `$.parseJSON` function. You can just assign it to the JavaScript variable like the following one:

```
data = <?= $my_json ?>; 
$.each(data.links, function(entryIndex, entry) {
    //do some stuff here
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Perumal93 -- that fixed it!